# XRegExp to accept all UTF-8 characters, space between words, to exclude a certain symbol, and no trailing spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, utf-8

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out the Regular Expression in XRegExp to accept these types of requirements in JavaScript:

- Accepts all UTF-8 characters
- Space between words are allowed, how only 1 space and not multiple.
- Allow all symbols for example: !#$%^&*()_-={}[] except: "@"
- No trailing spaces after or before the string for example:

`"Hello World!" //should be true`

`" Hello World! " //should be false`

`"Hello   World!" //should be false`

Here are the following examples that should pass:

`"ÅÅÅÅ 象形字 123" //should be true`

`"What's up? 123" //should be true`

`"!#$%^&*()_+=+" //should be true`

The following examples should fail:

`"hello@gmail.com" //should fail because of "@" symbol`

`"!@#$%^&*()_+=" //should fail because of "@" symbol`

More examples above

So far what I have is:

`XRegExp('^\\p{L}|[0-9]+$')`

Which is only accepting all UTF-8 characters and numbers.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I believe this RegExp (no need in XRegExp) - [`var rx = /^(?![^@]*@)(?!\s)(?![^]*\s$)(?!\S*\s\s)[^]*$/;`](http://jsfiddle.net/hwkLra3b/1/) - can be used. Is there any length restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on the usual RegExp powered with negative lookaheads:

```
^(?![^@]*@)(?![^]*\s\s)\S[^]{0,18}\S$
```

Breakdown:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![^@]*@)` - no `@` symbol
- `(?![^]*\s\s)` - no double whitespaces
- `\S[^]{0,18}\S` - a non-whitespace symbol (1), `[^]{0,18}` - 0 to 18 any characters and 1 non-whitespace (total max. 20, min. 2).
- `$` - end of string.

```js
var rx = /^(?![^@]*@)(?![^]*\s\s)\S[^]{0,18}\S$/;
document.body.innerHTML = rx.test("Hello World!") + " - must be true<br/>";// true
document.body.innerHTML += rx.test(" Hello World! ") + " - must be false<br/>"; //should be false
document.body.innerHTML += rx.test("Hello   World!") + " - must be false<br/>"; //should be false
document.body.innerHTML += rx.test("ÅÅÅÅ 象形字 123") + " - must be true<br/>"; //should be true
document.body.innerHTML += rx.test("What's up? 123") + " - must be true<br/>"; //should be true
document.body.innerHTML += rx.test("!#$%^&*()_+=+") + " - must be true<br/>"; //should be true
document.body.innerHTML += rx.test("hello@gmail.com") + " - must fail<br/>"; //should fail because of "@" symbol
document.body.innerHTML += rx.test("!@#$%^&*()_+=") + " - must fail<br/>"; //should fail because of "@" symbol
```

Comment: Wow this is amazing! you are the regex king. haha, I also forgot to mention that it had to be minimum length of 2 and maximum length of 20.

Comment: It is even better. I replaced the former regex overloaded with lookaheads, and the two of them - `(?!\s)(?![^]*\s$)` - are replaced with `\S[^]{0,18}\S` subpattern.